# Rename MainPage.xaml in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I would like to rename the mainpage, I have renamed the xaml name, cs name and inside the code, as well as navigate page name in WMAppManifest. but i still get error in App.xaml which says:"LocalizedStrings doesnt exist in clr-namespace:project1". Is there anything else i need to fix or is it not possible to rename the mainpage?

Comment: What is LocalizedStrings ?

Comment: You can rename the MainPage and what you did is correct. Issue may be because of something else in the app. Try 'rebuild'ing the app.

Comment: Did you do a solution-wide search for MainPage?

Comment: Try to add a new  item, giving this page the name you would like, then set it as the Navigation Page in WMAppManifest.xaml. Then, after you delete the defunct MainPage.xaml, do you still get the error you describe?

Comment: Did all what i did before and it works. Maybe vs needs restart